# Assign Class to simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Im trying to assign custom classes to my simple_form elements to modify with CSS and its just not working.. following the documentation, something like

```
<%= f.input :username, :input_html => { :class => 'special' } %>
```

Should work but does not...

Any clues? Thanks!!!

PS- This line is in a nested "f.simple_fields_for"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are embedded in a `fields_for` then it should be

```
<%= simple_for_object @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :fields do |field| %>
    <%= field.input :username, :input_html => {:class => 'special'} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I normally use haml, so my erb might be a bit off. but the idea is that if you are in a `fields_for` block you need to use the block variable of that block and not the variable for the parent form's block.